# How can I make a Matlab GUI that takes many input values and can be displayed without some of GUI off the screen?

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-figure

I am trying to read around 20 input values into variables with Matlab's inputdlg() function. When I use more than ~18 variables, the GUI becomes too tall for the screen. Is there a way I can fix this with inputdlg (besides calling the function twice)? And if there is no way with inputdlg(), is there a different Matlab function I could use for this purpose?

Here is my current code:

```
prompt = {'Enter a value:',... %answer 1
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 2
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 3
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 4
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 5
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 6
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 7
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 8
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 9
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 10
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 11
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 12
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 13
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 14
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 15
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 16
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 17
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 18
    };
title = 'Specifications';            
dims = [1 35];              % input field specifications
definput = {'0','0','1','0.5','2.0','15','0.3','1','1','2','1.0','20','0','3000','2^7','2','0','Y'};   % default values
answer = inputdlg(prompt,title,dims,definput);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `uitable` in a `uifigure` to get the data. It adds a scrollbar if the table exceeds its boundaries. Adding OK/Cancel `uibuttons` to the figure tells the program whether to accept or reject the data in the table.

In the code below, the data is passed to the main script via the global variable `dataOut`. `uiwait` forces the main script to wait until the dialog is closed.

```
prompt = {'Enter a value:',... %answer 1
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 2
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 3
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 4
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 5
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 6
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 7
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 8
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 9
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 10
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 11
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 12
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 13
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 14
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 15
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 16
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 17
    'Enter a value:',...       %answer 18
    };
title = 'Specifications';            
dims = [1 35];              % input field specifications
definput = {'0','0','1','0.5','2.0','15','0.3','1','1','2','1.0','20','0','3000','2^7','2','0','Y'};   % default values

% Create figure & uitable
fig = uifigure('Name',title,'Position',[100 100 500 500],...
    'CloseRequestFcn',@(fig,event) Cancel_Pushed(fig)); % Create figure, set window size and close request
tableData = {prompt{:};definput{:}}'; % Data for table
table = uitable(fig); % Create table
table.Position = [50 80 400 400]; % Set table size
table.Data = tableData; % Send data to table
table.ColumnEditable = [false,true]; % Allow input on second column

% Create buttons w/ callbacks
OK = uibutton(fig,'Position',[50 30 100 22],'Text','OK','ButtonPushedFcn', @(OK,event) OK_Pushed(fig,table));
Cancel = uibutton(fig,'Position',[170 30 100 22],'Text','Cancel','ButtonPushedFcn', @(Cancel,event) Cancel_Pushed(fig));

dataOut = []; % Declare global variable to retrieve data from callbacks
global dataOut; 

uiwait(fig); % Wait until figure is closed


function OK_Pushed(fig,table)
    global dataOut
    tableOut = table.Data; % Get data
    dataOut = tableOut(:,2); % Save table data
    delete(fig); % Close figure

end
function Cancel_Pushed(fig)
    global dataOut
    dataOut = {0}; % Return 0 if canceled
    delete(fig); % Close figure
end
```